# Xcode Subversion Control not able to commit any newly added physical file/folder

Tags: xcode, svn

I had created a new folder physically in my project's physical folder. Subsequently I dragged and dropped the new folder into my xcode project.

After i added the new folder into my xcode project, only the project file reflected the changes, but there is no any 'A' icon beside the new folder. And hence i can not commit the physical folder into my SVN as well.

Any clues for this?